# Autogenerated sql script, can't configure ID parameter

Tags: mysql

I have an error in my MySQL program, even though my friend doesn't get the error after he autogenerated it

```
    create database person;
CREATE TABLE person.`persons` (
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  FNAME VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  LNAME VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PHONE INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE INDEX ID_UNIQUE (ID ASC));
```

I get the error, that FIELD ID doesn't have a default value, even though I have specified it, how come this be? 
I have written it as AUTO_INCREMENT and NOT_NULL whenever I try to paste in some values I also get the error

the error occurs, when I try to insert some values into the table like such:

```
INSERT INTO `Person`.`PERSON` (`FNAME`, `LNAME`, `PHONE`) VALUES ('Kristoffer', 'Tølbøll', '6969');
INSERT INTO `Person`.`PERSON` (`FNAME`, `LNAME`, `PHONE`) VALUES ('Nioklai', 'Stein Bagger', '1234');
INSERT INTO `Person`.`PERSON` (`FNAME`, `LNAME`, `PHONE`) VALUES ('Sebastian', 'Ananasfar', '5475');
```

Comment: what error you got ?

Comment: your table name and insert query table name is not same so mysql engine will not found your table PERSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a typo. You wrote

```
CREATE TABLE person.`persons` /* notice the s at the table name */
```

And then, in query

```
INSERT INTO `Person`.`PERSON` /* notice the missing s */
```

The insert query can be written that way if you don't want to specify fields (by the way, you can remove the quotes around numeric values for int type fields, to avoid unnecessary implicit conversion from MySQL) :

```
INSERT INTO `person`.`persons` VALUES (default, 'Kristoffer', 'Tølbøll', 6969);
```